# How to call a shortcode in each post in the main blog post listing page?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm relatively new here. I tried to execute a shortcode which is [ssba] in every single post in their main listing page (please check the page http://www.theevidencenetwork.com.php54-1.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/news-events) but was unable to do so. When I view each post in their own page like when I click on any post listed there and view them the shortcode works just fine. But I want to show them in the main page as well.

How do I do that?

Comment: I believe if you apply `do_shortcode($content_of_post)` to each post in the loop, it will execute the shortcode. Though my confidence in that solution is not enough to justify a full answer! For what it's worth, I can tell you from having done this myself about a year ago, I know for sure it is 100% possible to do :P

Comment: "I tried to execute a shortcode" - and how was that?

Comment: I placed the shortcode after each post using wordpress' post editor which works fine only when I view the posts individually. But I want the shortcode works the same in the main blog where all the posts are listed. I hope this makes sense to you now. I'm sorry if I couldn't explain it clearly. I'm new with WP esp since the website uses a framework. Please do have a look at the site  http://www.theevidencenetwork.com.php54-1.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/news-events and I hope you'll understand what I meant to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm relatively new here too..

The shortcode is probably not showing because it's `the_excerpt()`, it doesn't render shortcodes or html.

There are a lot of ways to solve this 'problem'

I think you can try this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ssba_the_content_filter' );

function ssba_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    $new_content = $content;

    $new_content .= do_shortcode( '[ssba]' );

    return $new_content;
}
```

Put this code on your functions.php

This will automatically add the [ssba] shortcode at the end of every `the_content()` and `the_excerpt()` in your theme. 
With this solution you don't need to manually eneter this information on every post

if you want you can use conditional tags inside so you add only at the pages you want.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ssba_the_content_filter' );

function ssba_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    $new_content = $content;

    if( is_single() ) {
        $new_content .= do_shortcode( '[ssba]' );
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

or like AgmLauncher said, you can use `do_shortcode()`in the loop.

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 

        echo '<div>';
            the_content();
            echo do_shortcode('[ssba]');
        echo '</div>';
    } // end while
} // end if
```

sorry for bad english.